# On hover, how change several properties with jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a page full of thumbnail pictures.  On hovering over one, I want to enlarge it, without disturbing the layout of the rest of the pictures.

Each picture is in a wrapper div, kept stationary when the pic is enlarged

I can do it with CSS by:

1. changing the z-index from 0 to 1
2. changing the display property to 'absolute'
3. Setting left:0 and top:0   (just in case)
4. Then setting width:340px and height:auto (needed for ie8 I think).
   CSS

   .wrapper:hover >  .Img  { width:300px;  position: absolute;z-index:1; left:0; top:0; }

But I want to animate the increase in size.  I started using:
  $('.wrapper').hover(function() {...
but then read that hover can only have one function.

So I tried mouseenter and mouseleave without success.

What I tried is:

```
$('.Wrapper.).mouseenter(function()  {
    $('.Img').animate({ zIndex:1 },1,"swing" );                   /* this line works */
    document.getElementsByClassName('.Img').style.zIndex="1";       /*   this doesnt */
    document.getElementsByClassName('Img').style.position="absolute"/*   this doesnt */
    $('.Img').animate({ position:"absolute" },1,"swing");           /*   this doesnt */
    $('.Img').animate({width: '300px', height: '240px'},5000,"swing");
}); 
$("#testXX").mouseleave(function()  {
/*   with the reverse of above */
});
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please.

--- EDITED?ADDED THIS LATER: ---
Thanks for your ideas.  I've done more research and the issue seems to be:

With javascript, I don't know how to change the position to 'absolute', 
but I can now change the other properties.

```
document.getElementById(this).position='absolute';                   doesnt work
document.getElementsByClassName('.Img').style.position="absolute";   doesnt work
$('.Img').animate({ position:'absolute' },001,'swing');              doesnt work!
```

I guess I could use a mixture of CSS (to do the change to absolute) and Javascript (to do the other animation), but I'm concerned about the sequence/timing causing display effects on the rest of the page.

fyi: The CSS version is here:
[http://www.frog-records.co.uk/....](http://www.frog-records.co.uk/pages/frog-records-catalogue-chronologically)
or (if solved by the time you read this ) the animated version will be there ;-)

Comment: I believe this is a typo? `$('.Wrapper.)`

Answer (score 1):

In general: **Don't** use $(".Img") **multiple** times. Instead use one of the following:

```
// Chain your methods, e.g.:
$(".Img").css({position: 'absolute'}).animate({width: '500px'});
// or store it in a var and refer to that
var img = $(".Img"); img.css(/*something*/); img.animate(/*something*/);
```

I assume you have multiple .Wrapper, each with one image inside, and want to animate only one on hover. But your `$(".Img")`catches **all** elements with class "Img" on the whole page. On whatever .Wrapper you hover all images gets animated simultaneously. Instead:

```
$(".Wrapper").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".Img").animate(/*something*/); // animates all images on the page
    // inside the callback function the keyword 'this' (without quotes!) refers
    // to the one .Wrapper we are actual in. 'this' is called the context of the
    // function. We can pass the context to jQuery as a second argument:

    $(".Img", this).animate(/*something*/)
    // animates only the image of the .Wrapper we are actual in
});
```

Now I refer to the five lines inside your 'mouseenter' function:

**Line 1:** You can animate zIndex, because it has a numerical value, but it doesn't make sense. A valid zIndex is an integer (0, 1, 2, ...), but the animation outputs in-between values (like 0.25, 0.33, ...) some browsers may fail with. **Set zIndex with .css or .style.**

**Line 2, Line 3:** .getElementsByClassName() returns a NodeList (= a list with elements inside). The list itself has no style property. If you want to set style on elements inside this list, you must iterate over it.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName(".Img"), length = list.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) list[i].style.position = "absolute";
```

**Line 4:** Its impossible to animate position property. Position may be 'static', 'relative', 'absolute' or 'fixed', but contains no animatable number.

**Line 5:**  should work!       So your 'mouseenter' function may look like:

```
$(".Wrapper").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".Img", this).css({zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0})
                   .animate({width: '340px', height: '240px'}, 5000, 'swing');
});
```

At last: all functions relying on a single event ('mouseenter', 'click', ...) take only one function as their argument (callback). That means:

```
$("selector").mouseenter( /* Here you can pass only one function in */ );
// that looks like:
$("selector").mouseenter(function() { /* do something */ }); // but:
$("selector").mouseenter(function() {
    /* do something */ // means:
    // inside this single callback that is passed to a single-event-function
    // you can do what you want and call as much functions you need.
});
```

**'hover'** is **not** a single **event but** the **state** between the mouseenter event and the mouseleave event.  Thats why jQuery's .hover() is a shortcut for both mouseenter and mouseleave events together. It takes **one or two** callback functions and looks like:

```
$("selector").hover(function1, /* optional */ function2);
```

If there's only function1 it gets called when mouseenter fires and called again when mouseleave fires. If there are two callbacks function1 is called on mouseenter and function2 on mouseleave. **Inside** these both you can do anything like explained before.

At very last: In your code you attach the 'mouseleave' function to another element called **#testXX**. If you get some more problems, please update your question with the significant parts of your html.

Comment: Thanks @Martin-Ernst for a very instructive and helpful answer.  You've not only helped me, but anyone that later has a similar issue.
I thought that there must be a ... (".Img", this) ... construct but  couldn't find it anywhere - you've explained it admirably - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
$('.Wrapper').hover({function(){
    $(this).animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        /* etc */
    });
});
```

Comment: Since when there's a value `absolute` for the `display`?

Comment: My bad... haha position

Comment: Yes @MelencialUK it is (another of my!) typo's, but when I typed the question.  Tks.

Comment: Tks @Leeish for your:
$('.Wrapper').hover({function(){
    $(this).animate({
        position: 'absolute',

But I can't change the Wrapper (that has to stay there), it's the '.Img' that has to change.

Comment: I've applied all that I learnt from @Martin (above) and can now change all the properties on mouseenter & mouseleave.  But on mouseleave there is a display abberation/flicker because e.g. 'display:relative' gets applied before the width is reduced to the original size.

The code at issue is:
`code`
$(".F1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".I1", this).stop().animate({width: '120px', height: '107px'}, 100, 'swing');
    .delay(999).css({zIndex: 0, position: 'relative', left: 0, top: 0});

});
`/code`
Delay doesnt work, nor could I get setTimeout to work.
Any help is appreciated